# Is it possible on Drupal 8 to allow users register themselves and receive confirmation email?

Tags: drupal-8

On Drupal8 board  /admin/config/account setting,  I've checked box that allow users to register themselves and get approve from admin.
I’ve created  a new user account  and got confirmation as below:

“Thank you for applying for an account. Your account is currently pending approval by the site administrator.
In the meantime, a welcome message with further instructions has been sent to your email address.”

I’ve never got welcome message even so I could see the user that I’ve created under /admin/people - it was blocked. 
I’ve checked spam folders, used different browsers but there were no confirmation email as such…

So, I as admin, unblocked this account - but I still could not login since I don’t have any confirmation email with password.

I could only login user if I, as admin will provide  login id and password for user. 
Is it possible on Drupal 8 to allow users  register themselves  and receive confirmation email?
If so, how to do so? 
Or there is  only admin could register the users and users could not register themself?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess you host Drupal yourself? Are you sure your configuration for sendings mails is correct?

Comment: Yes, I've created 3 different accounts and all those accounts got emails from each other but no any confirmation email from Drupal8. Yes, I am admin on Drupal 8 and I try to pretend that I forgot admin password - and got: Further instructions have been sent to your email address. 

But i got no emails with instructions.

Comment: Do you mean all account got mails from Drupal (other than the account creation mail)?

Comment: not from Drupal I had zero... like it doesn't exist. but my other emails that not related drupal all were delivered. That I assume that my email are fine .Also I've got emails confirmations from program that used Wordpress and Ruby on Rails. So, i assume my hosting SMTP is fine.

Comment: Ok than I guess that your configuration to send mail with Drupal is broken. Drupal uses the configuration in the `php.ini` by default. Are you sure this is set correctly? Have you otherwise configured Drupal to send mails?

Comment: I didn't touch php.ini but i know Outgoing email server info. What if any need to change in php.ini or maybe hosting company could do that?

Comment: If you know the outgoing server (and it is SMTP) you can try using [this](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp) plugin. But this is only beta for Drupal 8. Depending on your hosting company you might or might not be able to edit the php.ini file directly. The configuration also depends on your OS. But I think this is a good point to start googling for and If you have a more specific question for the config just ask it here on SO, including your current configuration.

Comment: I've already install this plugin(find some info on internet)- doesn't do me any good - can't see email from drupal

Answer (score 0):

SMTP server requires authentication to be enabled. 
I’ve tried to send and test sending mail using account that is not connected to my hosting -  it wouldn’t  work.

So, I have set up a mailbox in the account, updated its details in SMTP AUTHENTICATION section as well as in E-MAIL OPTIONS section. 
I sent an email to my test  account by saving the configuration and it was successfully delivered.

So, the users could sign up, get confirmations by email and register themselves  by changing their passwords.